# Storing and Accessing Technical Documentation in VS.net

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using VS.net and TFS. In the past I have stored my technical documentation (explanatory documents etc) in TFS document WSS repository and linked it to my source code via the Story, Task or other work item. This has proved unsatisfactory in the long term because the documentation is not strongly linked to the code it describes.

What options do I have to link documentation to code in VS.net/TFS other than through the work item. I can think of two options immediately -

1) Add it as Content to the project or solution itself and store it in the source code control repository
2) Add it as a URL in the code header, and store it in the TFS WSS document store.

Both these seem unsatisfactory - (1) means the documentation is not available outside the SCCS, and (2) means the programmer has to hunt through code to find the documentation link (which could be anywhere in any header).

Are there any other options that are in common use ?

Phillip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a single golden answer to your question. But let me share how I do it.

Personally I split my documentation in technical and business documentation.
Technical documentation only consists of four documents:

- What are we building, short document that you can give to a new developer to get quickly up to speed what the project is all about.
- Instructions to compile. This document describes any steps a developer needs to take on a completely new machine to compile the code and run unit tests
- Instructions to deploy. All necessary information to deploy the app to a new environment
- Technologies. A list of technologies used in the project with links to more information if a developer needs to learn something.

This documentation is stored in a solution folder as part of the solution in Visual Studio.

Outside stakeholders can view this documentation through the web access of TFS. They can't change it however without having Visual Studio or Team Explorer and knowing how to use those.

For all other documentation we use SharePoint. TFS allows you to link Workitems to documents in SharePoint. We try to avoid any technical documentation in here.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting - you use TFS SCCS web access as the portal to publish the documents (or at least access them). I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you might consider is to create a new Work Item type called "document" and to have a hyperlink from here to the document location. Now you can create hard links between code files and changesets as well as PBI's to originating documentation.

In addition, when documents move you only have one place to update it.

Comment: How would the link between the code file and the Work Item work ? Work items are only linked to code through their changeset arn't they ? If I dont change the code but add a new piece of documentation covering that code, how would I know the document exists?

Comment: Good communication. You can't, and should not, replace the need for good communication as it hides dysfunction.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but here I am concerned with communication across time, not just between people. If I want to have my code maintainable for the next 5 years none of the people I currently communicate with may be in my team - I need my code to be intelligible and maintainable by strangers, so my documentation scheme must to intelligible over a period of time not just for the current team. Its a bit philosphical, but documents communicate to people who I dont yet, or may never, know.